# Error using RestResponse from RestEasy Reactive library

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to use the `RestResponse<T>` object from `org.jboss.resteasy.reactive` on the return of my application resources since the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` doesn't provide the generic type.

I am getting the error when I call this endpoint:

```
public RestResponse<List<SampleResponse>> findAll() {
    return ResponseBuilder.ok(sampleService.findAll()).build();
}
```

The error:

```
Request failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl cann
ot be cast to class org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.jaxrs.RuntimeDelegateImpl (org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl and org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.jaxrs.RuntimeDelegateImpl are in unnamed mo
dule of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @3c153a1)
```

My dependencies in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the problem... It was the order of dependecies. I switched `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` to the top and it is working now.

Answer (score 3):

With RESTEasy Reactive, you should use `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`. `quarkus-rest-client` may bring some RESTEasy classic classes that conflict with the reactive version